# Using $watch to update data, ng-repeat not reflecting changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of fooditems in `$scope.raw` and I want to show this data in columns so I'm changing the structure a bit. I do this in the `sortStuff()` function and store the updated data in `$scope.allfood`. There's a $watch that calls `sortStuff()` every time anything changes in `$scope.raw` (I'm using drag and drop to change the food category):

```
$scope.$watch('raw', function(){
    $scope.allfood = $scope.sortStuff();
    console.log($scope.allfood);
}, true);
```

This is what happens when food is dragged around:

```
receive:function(event, ui) {
    var issueScope = angular.element(ui.item).scope();
    scope.$apply(function() {
        var recp = _.find(scope.raw, function(lineitem){
            return lineitem.name === issueScope.receipe.name;
        })
        recp.cat = scope.col.name;
    })

    $(ui.item).remove(); // remove DOM
}
```

Basically, I search for the right object inside `$scope.raw` and change `cat` to new category for the food. I also delete the dom element because I'm counting on ng-repeat to refresh the view. This seems to work fine: console.log inside $watch shows that the object is being moved to the right category and the data looks what it should look like. However, visually, ng-repeat doesn't reflect the data.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8Fa7/).

Dragging an item from B to C works fine. Dragging one from A to B, makes two items from B disappear... the results are very inconsistent and I have no idea what is happening.

Any ideas what is going wrong? Or maybe any suggestions for a better way to do this?

Comment: You should be using $watchCollection('raw', function() {}); but I've done that and am still seeing the same issues in my app...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `ng-repeat` directive adds the property `$$hashKey` to every element in the list. This property is used by the directive to associate DOM elements with array elements.

Because you are passing the elements by reference, the `ng-repeat` directive writes the `$$hashKey` property directly into the objects of your `$scope.raw` array. A simple workaround is to copy the objects before inserting them into the `$scope.allfood` object.

```
_.each($scope.raw, function(recp){
    recp = _.clone(recp);
    switch(recp.cat){
        ...
    }
});
```

Now the `ng-repeat` updates the objects of `$scope.allfood`, while the objects of `$scope.raw` remain untouched.

See the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8Fa7/5/

Comment: Thanks, that works! Two questions though: is it possible to clone an object without properties such as `$$hashKey` that were added by angular? Also, do you think there's a better way to do this? The fact that angular regenerates the entire `$scope.allfood` on every change can't be good for performance and I'd like to avoid it somehow.

Comment: `angular.copy` provides a way to create a deep copy of an array or object without properties such as `$$hashKey`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Comment: You could probably keep track of all changes to the `$scope.raw` array and only modify the `$scope.allfood` object based on the tracked changes. I don't think this brings a notable performance improvement as long as the list is small though.

Comment: angular.copy does what I need. Thanks!